# StringSplitOptions.None doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, string, split

I'm trying to convert a string to string[] using two delimiters and I want delimiters to be null strings in resultant string[] nodes

```
string source = "(('CO.IN'.bit = C) OR ('CO.IN'.bit = V))";
char[] delimiters = new char[] { '(', ')' };
string[] parts = source.Split(delimiters,StringSplitOptions.None);
```

The expected result for string[] parts is:

```
[null]
[null]
'CO.IN'.bit = C
[null]
' OR '
[null]
'CO.IN'.bit = V
[null]
[null]
```

But the result obtained is:

```
[null]
[null]
'CO.IN'.bit = C
' OR '
'CO.IN'.bit = V
[null]
[null]
```

I miss two nodes and I don't understand why.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Try adding white space as a split character too, if that doesnt change your business logic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your assumption that you get `null` values for the delimiters is wrong. You get an empty string if there is no text between two delimiters.

The first two empty strings ([null] in your post) appear because there is no text between the start of the string and the first delimiter and no text between the first and second delimiter.

But `C) OR ('CO` (part of your string) can be split into `C`, `OR` and `'CO` without an empty string between two delimiters.

Comment: The emtpy values are not null, but String.Empty.

Comment: You're right, I assumed they were nulls because the auther of the question wrote it.

Comment: Oh! Thank you! I missundesrstood the documentation. Thanks a lot, has been so helpful. It changes a little bit my iterator but works great!!

Answer (score 4):

The output is OK. **Note the space before and after the OR**. The expected value is not what you say. The output "OR" is " OR " not "OR".

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong with how functions works.
I expected delimiters to turn into null nodes of the array.
But Dirk helped me to understand what it does.

The result obtained is:

```
[null]
[null]
'CO.IN'.bit = C
' OR '
'CO.IN'.bit = V
[null]
[null]
```

This means delimietrs are between strings

```
[null]
Delimiter
[null]
Delimiter
'CO.IN'.bit = C
Delimiter
' OR '
Delimiter
'CO.IN'.bit = V
Delimiter
[null]
Delimiter
[null]
```

I assumed a delimiter is always at the end of every string, but not in the last node.
My loop worked well.
Know which delimiter is used is another battle.

Thanks a lot!!